# Is there no way to send email using SMTP without plugin or custom coding?

Tags: email

This question is part of my effort to solve a problem where after installing some theme, new sign-ups won't get activation emails.

I have read an [articles](https://www.a2hosting.com/kb/installable-applications/optimization-and-configuration/wordpress2/sending-e-mail-in-wordpress) about how wordpress sends emails. It mentions a plugin or using `wp_mail` function. From my Joomla mindset, I expect some place on the back end where I can set SMTP infos for the admin's email. Does it exist?

Comment: yes it's very easy to do this in Joomla's backend, so I understand the confusion :-)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There’s no setting. You’ll need a plugin.